# Change Country in Adsense while set up

Tags: adsense

I was trying to set up my account on Adsense. However, I have chosen the wrong country at the beginning and pressed proceed, when I released what mistake I have done I tried to get back and change it and I can't.

I searched on the internet how to change the account's country; all advice to click on payment or settings buttons on the left, but they are all inactive options as the account is still under set up.

Now I can't continue the setup process, as Adsense won't accept my Zipcode since the country that I have entered is wrong.

Could you please advise what to be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks, I have put all the information that I have; and there's no other place to find a solution other than stackoverflow, what can I do?

Comment: I have been working for 2 years on my website, and this will go to the drain if I couldn't active Adsense account

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I would suggest to ask the question to a more relevant site like https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or even better https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will do many thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Forget old account & gmail. Create a new one, Use different name & address while signing up then after approval change to your correct info before you get your pin generated. It's easy if you have a quality site and traffic. All the best! :)